# Variable scope and inheritance for QUnit tests in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, inheritance, scope, phantomjs, qunit

I have some code which seems to work in every environment except when running it in PhantomJS, which I am using for testing purposes in a headless CI environment.

Here's the code:

```
function NumericalAxis (variable1, variable2) {
    do something with variable2
    GenericAxis.call(this, variable1);
}

NumericalAxis.prototype = Object.create(GenericAxis.prototype);

Object.assign(NumericalAxis.prototype, {
    init: function(...) {
        do something
    },

    ...
});
```

When running in PhantomJS, I get a "Can't find variable: GenericAxis". Could anybody enlighten me on some poor practice I might have applied, or some obscure manner in which PhantomJS evaluates the code ?

Thanks,

Ryan

Comment: My guess is that you are not including the JS file in your tests that contains the `GenericAxis` constructor in it, hence it is not defined. In other words, I don't think this has anything to do with Phantom, but rather with your testing setup.

Comment: The file is included, and the QUnit test page (which is executed by PhantomJS) works perfectly in my browser. Also the tests work in Nightmare, so I think I will simply be using Nightmare from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with `Object.assign` which is not supported in PhantomJS, since it is part of ES2015

see: https://github.com/wallabyjs/public/issues/579